# digital elevation model data help?

Tags: elevation, file-formats, dxf, stl

I know little about geographic data.  I am trying to get a file of elevation data for the United Kingdom so that I can import it into a CAD program and convert it to an *.stl or *.dxf format.  I intend to use a 3D CNC router to make a physical model of this data.

Can anyone point me anywhere or explain how I would acquire data in this format of data I can convert?

Answer (score 1):

You do not say what resolution of data you are looking for.  The obvious place to look for UK data is the OS, our national mapping agency!  They now offer free data called [OS Terrain 50](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/terrain-50.html).

I you are looking for higher resolution data for the UK and have money to spend then I suggest you look at [NEXTMap](http://www2.getmapping.com/Products/NEXTMap)

Answer (score 1):

SRTM global 30 m for europe will work as well.

You can get it from [earth explorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/).

You can just use QGIS with this [plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DEMto3D/) to convert the data in one step. No need to go into CAD.